# Getting data in angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm stuck with extracting data, I got the source listed but not sure how to do dates in this example. Would be amazing if somebody could guide me through.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AyimaData</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat="x in ayima">
        <p>{{ x.domain }}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("http://dfjb.webcindario.com/dataAyima.php")
        .success(function(response) {
          $scope.ayima = response.marketIntel;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          // something went wrong
        });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Data is looking like this

```
{
  "marketIntel": [
    {
      "domain": "apple.com",
      "scores": {
        "2015-09-26": 9.9,
        "2015-09-27": 9.73,
        "2015-09-28": 9.91,
        "2015-09-29": 9.4,
        "2015-09-30": 10.16,
        "2015-10-01": 9.59,
        "2015-10-02": 10.16,
        "2015-10-03": 9.67,
        "2015-10-04": 10.13,
        "2015-10-05": 10.33,
        "2015-10-06": 9.6,
        "2015-10-07": 9.97,
        "2015-10-08": 10.14,
        "2015-10-09": 9.59,
        "2015-10-10": 9.49,
        "2015-10-11": 9.56,
        "2015-10-12": 9.57,
        "2015-10-13": 9.57,
        "2015-10-14": 9.52,
        "2015-10-15": 9.94,
        "2015-10-16": 9.5,
        "2015-10-17": 9.59,
        "2015-10-18": 10.19,
        "2015-10-19": 10.03,
        "2015-10-20": 9.59,
        "2015-10-21": 10.12,
        "2015-10-22": 9.83,
        "2015-10-23": 9.96,
        "2015-10-24": 9.46,
        "2015-10-25": 9.54
      }
    },
    {
      "domain": "techradar.com",
      "scores": {
        "2015-09-26": 8.66,
        "2015-09-27": 9.16,
        "2015-09-28": 9.07,
        "2015-09-29": 8.98,
        "2015-09-30": 9.14,
        "2015-10-01": 8.9,
        "2015-10-02": 9.07,
        "2015-10-03": 8.92,
        "2015-10-04": 9.12,
        "2015-10-05": 9.5,
        "2015-10-06": 9.41,
        "2015-10-07": 9.21,
        "2015-10-08": 9.28,
        "2015-10-09": 9.38,
        "2015-10-10": 9.5,
        "2015-10-11": 8.85,
        "2015-10-12": 9.38,
        "2015-10-13": 9,
        "2015-10-14": 8.87,
        "2015-10-15": 8.9,
        "2015-10-16": 9.06,
        "2015-10-17": 9.03,
        "2015-10-18": 8.87,
        "2015-10-19": 9.34,
        "2015-10-20": 9.14,
        "2015-10-21": 8.87,
        "2015-10-22": 9.34,
        "2015-10-23": 9.19,
        "2015-10-24": 9.02,
        "2015-10-25": 9.4
      }
    },
    {
      "domain": "carphonewarehouse.com",
      "scores": {
        "2015-09-26": 7.89,
        "2015-09-27": 7.39,
        "2015-09-28": 7.66,
        "2015-09-29": 7.37,
        "2015-09-30": 7.31,
        "2015-10-01": 7.33,
        "2015-10-02": 7.46,
        "2015-10-03": 7.39,
        "2015-10-04": 7.43,
        "2015-10-05": 7.46,
        "2015-10-06": 7.35,
        "2015-10-07": 7.39,
        "2015-10-08": 7.98,
        "2015-10-09": 7.79,
        "2015-10-10": 7.63,
        "2015-10-11": 7.65,
        "2015-10-12": 7.6,
        "2015-10-13": 7.85,
        "2015-10-14": 7.46,
        "2015-10-15": 7.88,
        "2015-10-16": 7.66,
        "2015-10-17": 7.3,
        "2015-10-18": 7.26,
        "2015-10-19": 7.37,
        "2015-10-20": 7.41,
        "2015-10-21": 7.21,
        "2015-10-22": 7.26,
        "2015-10-23": 7.17,
        "2015-10-24": 7.21,
        "2015-10-25": 7.14
      }
    },
    {
      "domain": "samsung.com",
      "scores": {
        "2015-09-26": 6.99,
        "2015-09-27": 7.03,
        "2015-09-28": 7.1,
        "2015-09-29": 7.19,
        "2015-09-30": 7.21,
        "2015-10-01": 7.16,
        "2015-10-02": 6.99,
        "2015-10-03": 6.99,
        "2015-10-04": 6.92,
        "2015-10-05": 6.92,
        "2015-10-06": 6.93,
        "2015-10-07": 6.95,
        "2015-10-08": 6.96,
        "2015-10-09": 6.91,
        "2015-10-10": 6.88,
        "2015-10-11": 7.09,
        "2015-10-12": 7.07,
        "2015-10-13": 7.17,
        "2015-10-14": 7.24,
        "2015-10-15": 7.06,
        "2015-10-16": 7.02,
        "2015-10-17": 7.08,
        "2015-10-18": 6.98,
        "2015-10-19": 6.91,
        "2015-10-20": 7.13,
        "2015-10-21": 6.94,
        "2015-10-22": 6.96,
        "2015-10-23": 7.12,
        "2015-10-24": 7.13,
        "2015-10-25": 6.94
      }
    },
    {
      "domain": "amazon.co.uk",
      "scores": {
        "2015-09-26": 5.28,
        "2015-09-27": 5.19,
        "2015-09-28": 5.23,
        "2015-09-29": 5.32,
        "2015-09-30": 5.33,
        "2015-10-01": 5.25,
        "2015-10-02": 5.25,
        "2015-10-03": 5.17,
        "2015-10-04": 4.96,
        "2015-10-05": 5.15,
        "2015-10-06": 5.27,
        "2015-10-07": 5.23,
        "2015-10-08": 5.36,
        "2015-10-09": 5.15,
        "2015-10-10": 5.02,
        "2015-10-11": 5.09,
        "2015-10-12": 5.08,
        "2015-10-13": 5.12,
        "2015-10-14": 5.14,
        "2015-10-15": 5.17,
        "2015-10-16": 5.25,
        "2015-10-17": 5.18,
        "2015-10-18": 5.09,
        "2015-10-19": 5.09,
        "2015-10-20": 5.18,
        "2015-10-21": 5.32,
        "2015-10-22": 5.33,
        "2015-10-23": 5.26,
        "2015-10-24": 5.23,
        "2015-10-25": 5.31
      }
    },
    {
      "domain": "trustedreviews.com",
      "scores": {
        "2015-09-26": 3.98,
        "2015-09-27": 4.45,
        "2015-09-28": 4.14,
        "2015-09-29": 4.4,
        "2015-09-30": 4.36,
        "2015-10-01": 4.95,
        "2015-10-02": 4.95,
        "2015-10-03": 4.53,
        "2015-10-04": 4.52,
        "2015-10-05": 4.72,
        "2015-10-06": 5.01,
        "2015-10-07": 4.82,
        "2015-10-08": 4.67,
        "2015-10-09": 4.66,
        "2015-10-10": 4.91,
        "2015-10-11": 4.87,
        "2015-10-12": 4.75,
        "2015-10-13": 4.78,
        "2015-10-14": 5.15,
        "2015-10-15": 4.83,
        "2015-10-16": 4.75,
        "2015-10-17": 5.04,
        "2015-10-18": 5,
        "2015-10-19": 5.05,
        "2015-10-20": 5.04,
        "2015-10-21": 5.13,
        "2015-10-22": 5.57,
        "2015-10-23": 5.38,
        "2015-10-24": 5.18,
        "2015-10-25": 5.26
      }
    },
    {
      "domain": "gsmarena.com",
      "scores": {
        "2015-09-26": 4.43,
        "2015-09-27": 4.31,
        "2015-09-28": 4.14,
        "2015-09-29": 4.48,
        "2015-09-30": 4.41,
        "2015-10-01": 4.35,
        "2015-10-02": 4.48,
        "2015-10-03": 4.41,
        "2015-10-04": 4.4,
        "2015-10-05": 4.46,
        "2015-10-06": 4.26,
        "2015-10-07": 4.65,
        "2015-10-08": 4.49,
        "2015-10-09": 4.79,
        "2015-10-10": 4.76,
        "2015-10-11": 4.68,
        "2015-10-12": 4.69,
        "2015-10-13": 4.5,
        "2015-10-14": 4.51,
        "2015-10-15": 4.78,
        "2015-10-16": 4.5,
        "2015-10-17": 4.59,
        "2015-10-18": 4.75,
        "2015-10-19": 4.8,
        "2015-10-20": 4.67,
        "2015-10-21": 4.58,
        "2015-10-22": 4.91,
        "2015-10-23": 4.92,
        "2015-10-24": 4.8,
        "2015-10-25": 4.76
      }
    },
    {
      "domain": "wikipedia.org",
      "scores": {
        "2015-09-26": 4.57,
        "2015-09-27": 4.55,
        "2015-09-28": 4.51,
        "2015-09-29": 4.54,
        "2015-09-30": 4.39,
        "2015-10-01": 4.57,
        "2015-10-02": 4.48,
        "2015-10-03": 4.47,
        "2015-10-04": 4.42,
        "2015-10-05": 4.3,
        "2015-10-06": 4.64,
        "2015-10-07": 4.78,
        "2015-10-08": 4.61,
        "2015-10-09": 4.62,
        "2015-10-10": 4.93,
        "2015-10-11": 4.74,
        "2015-10-12": 4.56,
        "2015-10-13": 4.65,
        "2015-10-14": 4.62,
        "2015-10-15": 4.64,
        "2015-10-16": 4.62,
        "2015-10-17": 4.5,
        "2015-10-18": 4.66,
        "2015-10-19": 4.53,
        "2015-10-20": 4.5,
        "2015-10-21": 4.48,
        "2015-10-22": 4.37,
        "2015-10-23": 4.59,
        "2015-10-24": 4.57,
        "2015-10-25": 4.54
      }
    },
    {
      "domain": "argos.co.uk",
      "scores": {
        "2015-09-26": 1.97,
        "2015-09-27": 2.11,
        "2015-09-28": 1.79,
        "2015-09-29": 2.08,
        "2015-09-30": 1.86,
        "2015-10-01": 2.08,
        "2015-10-02": 1.95,
        "2015-10-03": 2.15,
        "2015-10-04": 1.83,
        "2015-10-05": 1.81,
        "2015-10-06": 2.09,
        "2015-10-07": 1.82,
        "2015-10-08": 1.87,
        "2015-10-09": 2.25,
        "2015-10-10": 2.24,
        "2015-10-11": 2.15,
        "2015-10-12": 2.31,
        "2015-10-13": 2.43,
        "2015-10-14": 2.29,
        "2015-10-15": 2.17,
        "2015-10-16": 2.38,
        "2015-10-17": 2.3,
        "2015-10-18": 2.16,
        "2015-10-19": 2.14,
        "2015-10-20": 2.39,
        "2015-10-21": 2.18,
        "2015-10-22": 2.09,
        "2015-10-23": 2.12,
        "2015-10-24": 2.33,
        "2015-10-25": 2.32
      }
    },
    {
      "domain": "o2.co.uk",
      "scores": {
        "2015-09-26": 2.81,
        "2015-09-27": 2.98,
        "2015-09-28": 2.85,
        "2015-09-29": 3.1,
        "2015-09-30": 2.92,
        "2015-10-01": 2.9,
        "2015-10-02": 2.63,
        "2015-10-03": 2.9,
        "2015-10-04": 2.67,
        "2015-10-05": 2.63,
        "2015-10-06": 2.75,
        "2015-10-07": 2.74,
        "2015-10-08": 2.75,
        "2015-10-09": 2.77,
        "2015-10-10": 2.62,
        "2015-10-11": 2.75,
        "2015-10-12": 2.86,
        "2015-10-13": 2.88,
        "2015-10-14": 2.91,
        "2015-10-15": 2.86,
        "2015-10-16": 2.85,
        "2015-10-17": 2.96,
        "2015-10-18": 2.87,
        "2015-10-19": 2.78,
        "2015-10-20": 2.71,
        "2015-10-21": 2.76,
        "2015-10-22": 2.58,
        "2015-10-23": 2.4,
        "2015-10-24": 2.34,
        "2015-10-25": 2.31
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Much apriciated for any pointers

Comment: @Manwal just updated the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Actually you wants to get `key` and `value` of object

Try following `HTML`:

```
<div data-ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat="x in ayima">
        <p>{{ x.domain }}</p>
        <p ng-repeat="(key, value) in x.scores">{{key}},{{value}}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

## See [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/y2v0zN6uJZv4Tlpyxtwc?p=preview)

Comment: Downvoter add comment here. And check this is working or not.

Comment: Updated answer by adding demo.

Answer (score 0):

I would transform the original json to keep things clear and simpler in the angularjs side....

```
$http.get("http://dfjb.webcindario.com/dataAyima.php")
    .success(function(response) {
      var transformedMarketIntel = response.marketIntel.map(function(market){
        var scoreObjs = [];
        for (var date in market.scores) {
           scoreObjs.push({date: date, score: market.scores[date]});
        }
        return {
           domain: market.domain, 
           scores: scoreObjs
        };
      });
      $scope.ayima = transformedMarketIntel;
    })
```

and then use the regular and clearer directive form:

```
<p ng-repeat="score in x.scores">{{score.date}}</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's good if you do it like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AyimaData</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat="x in ayima">
        <p>{{ x.domain }}</p>
        <p ng-repeat="(key,value) in x.scores">{{key}}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("http://dfjb.webcindario.com/dataAyima.php")
        .success(function(response) {
          $scope.ayima = response.marketIntel;

        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          // something went wrong
        });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

To summarize:

You have to use

```
ng-repeat="(key,value) in x.scores"
```

and then call

```
{{key}}
```

which is a date.

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JaLGqQiotStHQ8cfH3zE?p=preview)